# ¿Cómo comparar fechas mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito mostrar a través de una consulta mysql fechas para que los eventos no se traslapen.

Tengo 3 eventos agregados:

```
evento # | fecha_inicio | fecha_fin | id_espacio

evento 1 | 2020-02-23 09:00:00 | 2020-02-23 21:00:00 | 30
evento 2 | 2020-02-24 10:00:00 | 2020-02-24 20:00:00 | 30
evento 3 | 2020-02-25 07:00:00 | 2020-02-25 19:00:00 | 30
```

- Al actualizar la fecha_inicio/fecha_fin no debo traslapar con el evento anterior/siguiente.
- Tomando el evento 2 como ejemplo no puedo colocar como fecha_inicio 2020-02-23 08:00:00 porque me encuentro con la fecha_inicio del evento 1 que quedaría entre la nueva fecha_inicio y la fecha_inicio ya existente.

**Esta consulta está completamente mal, únicamente la agrego para mostrar qué tengo hasta ahora:**

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(a.fecha_fin), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dia_anterior 
FROM evnts a 
WHERE a.id_espacio = 30
AND id_evento = 87
ORDER BY a.fecha_inicio, a.fecha_fin ASC;
```

Alguna idea...?

Comment: Coloca algo de código que hayas intentado realizar y no te sale, para que alguien pueda ayudarte con la solución.

Comment: La respuesta no va en la pregunta amigo para eso abajo dispones de la zona de respuestas

Comment: Cierto, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he encontrado la solución:

```
SELECT count(*) as traslape
FROM evnts a 
WHERE '2020-02-23 08:00:00' <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(a.fecha_inicio), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS fecha_inicio_anterior FROM evnts a where a.id_evento = 87)
OR '2020-02-23 08:00:00' <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(CONCAT(a.fecha_fin), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS fecha_fin_anterior FROM evnts a where a.id_evento = 87)
AND a.id_espacio = 30
AND id_evento = 87
ORDER BY a.fecha_inicio, a.fecha_fin ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si comparas campos de  tipo datetime estas comparando fecha y hora, pero si quieres comparar solo la fecha basta con que uses date, no estoy muy seguro de si solo quieres comparar la fecha o también la hora pero en ambos casos puedes usa `datetime >=` con esto obtendremos todos los registros con fecha mayor o igual al inicio del día de comparación.

para obtener las fechas yo usaría

`SELECT id_evento, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin FROM evnts WHERE fecha_fin >= CAST ('2020-02-23' AS datetime)`

hice la consulta de id_evento pensando en que querrás saber el evento y la fecha de inicio y final de dicho evento.

Suerte